# Deselect contents of a textbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, focus

I understand that with javascript you can select the contents of a textbox with the following code (in jQuery):

```
$("#txt1").select();
```

Is there a way to do the opposite?  To deselect the content of a textbox?  I have the focus event of a series of textboxes set to select the contents within them.  There are times now that I want to focus a particular textbox WITHOUT selecting it.  What I am planning on doing is calling the focus event for this particular textbox, but then follow it with a call to deselect it.

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
});

//code....

$("#txt1").focus();

//some code here to deselect the contents of this textbox
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

what about this:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
  this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = -1;
});
```

Comment: could it be that firefox was taking up 1.5GB of ram at the time of this slowness? mine likes to do that right before i kill -9 it

Answer (score 8):

If you just assign the value of the textbox to itself, it should deselect the text.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` attribute. But for some reason, setting these on focus event doesn't work (I have no idea why). To make it work, set the attributes after a small interval.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txt1').focus(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        // set selection start, end to 0
        $('#txt1').attr('selectionStart',0);
        $('#txt1').attr('selectionEnd',0);
      },50);  // call the function after 50ms
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

To "focus a particular textbox WITHOUT selecting it":
I would use the part of the [patched jquery plugin jquery-fieldselection](https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection/blob/bc33fa60a4c8f5d7553fe6cd10ee0f71825ce83f/jquery-fieldselection.js)

using that you can call

```
$('#my_text_input').setSelection({"start":0, "end":0}); // leaves the cursor at the left
```

or use this reduced version that places the cursor at the end of the text (by default)

```
(function() {
var fieldSelection = {
    setSelection: function() {
        var e = (this.jquery) ? this[0] : this, len = this.val().length || ;
        var args = arguments[0] || {"start":len, "end":len};
        /* mozilla / dom 3.0 */
        if ('selectionStart' in e) {
            if (args.start != undefined) {
                e.selectionStart = args.start;
            }
            if (args.end != undefined) {
                e.selectionEnd = args.end;
            }
            e.focus();
        }
        /* exploder */
        else if (document.selection) {
            e.focus();
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            if (args.start != undefined) {
                range.moveStart('character', args.start);
                range.collapse();
            }
            if (args.end != undefined) {
                range.moveEnd('character', args.end);
            }
            range.select();
        }
        return this;
    }
};
jQuery.each(fieldSelection, function(i) { jQuery.fn[i] = this; });
})();
```

used this way:

```
$('#my_text_input').setSelection(); // leaves the cursor at the right
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than selecting and then deselecting, why not just temporarily store a boolean on the dom element?

```
 $("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
     if($(this).skipFocus) return;
     $(this).select();
 });

 //code....

 $("#txt1").skipFocus = true;
 $("#txt1").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a simple solution

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
});

$("input[type=text]").blur(function() {
    $('input[type="hidden"][value=""]').select();
});

//code....

$("#txt1").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution without jquery

```
<input type="text" onblur="this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = -1;">
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to deselect a text box using jQuery do the following:

```
   $(your_input_selector).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $(your_input_selector).removeAttr('disabled');
```