# How can I turn off the default textbox behaviour that pre-selects any existing text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to prevent the default textbox behaviour where any existing text is pre-selected when you tab into the textbox?

Note: must work in ie 7&8.

Comment: Have you tried using the text-selection apis `onblur`?

Comment: @Jakub What text-selection API?

Comment: Yeah calling it an API is maybe a bit of an euphemism. I meant `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's efforts. Hadnt realised it would be so tricky, particularly to get cross browser support.

Answer (score 0):

See [Deselect contents of a textbox with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794583/deselect-contents-of-a-textbox-with-javascript)

EDIT: Working example:

```
<html>
  <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>google.load("jquery", "1.5.0")</script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#mytextbox').focus(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $this.attr('selectionStart', 0);
                $this.attr('selectionEnd', 0);
            }, 0);
        });
    });
  </script>
  <body>
    <input id="mytextbox" value="hej hej hej">
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternative solution:

```
    $('#mytextbox').focus(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.val($this.val());
        }, 0);
    });
```

The first example will place the cursor before any text in the text box, while the second example will place the cursor after any text (only tested in Chromium, YMMV).

Comment: @Šime, your jsfiddle is not correct, you have multiple input fields with the same id, if you use a class or input selector the answer works.

Comment: @Mark Yes, you're right. I copy-pasted the input from your code multiple times and I didn't notice that it had an ID set. The correct demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Cmpse/3/

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to use setTimeout to offer a small delay to make this function correctly.

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(event) {
    var $box = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $box.val($box.val());
    }, 0);
});
```

Or per Šime suggestion this could even be made simpler..

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
    setTimeout(function(t) { t.value = t.value; }, 0, this);
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/9dLww/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, was set to use mootools doh!, fixed

Comment: @Šime, thanks I am always amazed the different ways js can be made simpler.

Comment: @Mark Yea, "JavaScript is amazing" is my tagline over at ecmazing.com `:)`

Comment: @Mark several problems: IE8 the caret is set to the first character - not good. In Firefox is doesn't work at all, whole text is still selected. In FF it's because the text must be changed first so nice hack will be `$box.val(" " + $box.val()).val($box.val().substr(1));` as for IE, should be simple enough to set caret position manually - feel free to edit your answer with both fixes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    var t = this, l = this.value.length;
    function f() { selec.set(t, l, l); }
    setTimeout(f, 0);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/evDuz/7/

The demo uses this script (for selection): http://vidasp.net/js/selection.js

---

**Update:**

If you don't care about IE (which doesn't support `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`) then this would be the best solution:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    function f(o) { o.selectionStart = o.selectionEnd = o.value.length; }
    setTimeout(f, 0, this);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/evDuz/5/

Comment: @Keep I wasn't aware that IE does not treat the third argument of the setTimeout call as an argument of the passed in function. I have updated my demo to make it work in IE too.