# Deselect text with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two input tag with numeric id in a form in one html page. On focus, I would like to set value of the second input from first and second character of the first input. Then I want to deselect the selected text in second input. There is a way to do that?
I wrote this HTML code:

```
<label>Num. Fattura:
        <input type="text" name="numfattura1" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13" id="1" />
    </label>
    <label>Importo:
        <input type="text" name="importo1" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>Num. Fattura:
        <input type="text" name="numfattura2" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13" id="2" onfocus="twoDigits(2)" />
    </label>
    <label>Importo:
        <input type="text" name="importo2" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13" />
    </label>
    <br />
```

And this javascript function:

```
function twoDigits(id){
    var previousId = id - 1;
    var prevoiusValue = document.getElementById(previousId).value;
    document.getElementById(id).value = prevoiusValue.substring(0,2);
    document.selection.empty();
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
}
```

I can't find how to deselect the text that is selected automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794583/deselect-contents-of-a-textbox-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using JQuery :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set selectionStart and selectionEnd using setTimeOut.

http://jsfiddle.net/enQvT/   works in firefox.

```
function twoDigits(id){
    var previousId = id - 1;
    var prevoiusValue = document.getElementById(previousId).value;

    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    setTimeout(function() {
               elem.selectionStart=0;
                elem.selectionEnd=0;
                }, 0);
    elem.value = prevoiusValue.substring(0,2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `.focus()` on a another form element.

Comment: Thank you; but I can't... After value change of second input , I have to modify the text...

Comment: @AndreaVenanzi, then I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can also empty and refill the input.
If you want to test:

```
<input type="textfield" id="aaa" value="aaa" />
<input type="textfield" id="bbb" value="bbb" onmouseover="empty()"  />

<script>
var empty = function() {
    var ipt = document.getElementById('aaa');
    var iptval = ipt.value;
    ipt.value = "";
    ipt.value = iptval;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure? How are you calling this? It works great for me.

Comment: I call your function (modified in var empty = function(id) {
    var ipt = document.getElementById(id);) in my twoDigits(id) function with: empty(id); In Safari it doesn't work, the text remain selected :(