# How to focus input, and deselect text inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am currently wanting to focus the first input element, without selecting the preset value text inside the input element. How can I focus my input element, and then deselect the text inside it? My current focus jQuery is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='title']").focus();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794583/deselect-contents-of-a-textbox-with-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='title']").focus();
    $("input[name='title']").val($("input[name='title']").val());
});
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='title']").each(function(){
        this.focus();
        this.selectionEnd = this.selectionStart;
    });
});
```

Comment: `this.selectionEnd = this.selectionStart` will put the cursor in the beginning of the input element contents.`this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd` will put the cursor in the end of the input element contents.

Answer (score 4):

This is based on Danilo Valente's answer above. I found that on Chrome I had to use a tiny delay before calling `this.selectionEnd = this.selectionStart`, otherwise the input text would remain selected:

This works for me on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE (tested IE 10)

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    var input = this;
    setTimeout(function() { input.selectionStart = input.selectionEnd; }, 1);
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rangfu/300ah0ax/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='title']").focus(function()
{ 
    var elem = $(this);

    elem.val(elem.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would like to add some enhanced solution that also cares of the actual caret positioning on deselect.

I utilized the following `input` element methods:

```
<input (blur)="onLocalFocusOut()" (click)="onInputClick($event)" (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)" />
```

And the methods look as the following:

```
public onInputClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (!this._initialSelectAll) {
        (event.target as HTMLInputElement).select();
        this._initialSelectAll = true;
    }
}

public onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (this._initialSelectAll) {
        (event.target as HTMLInputElement).selectionStart = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).selectionEnd = 0;
    }
}

public onLocalFocusOut(): void {
    this._initialSelectAll = false;
    this.onFocusChange(false);
}
```

Such a setup ensures that for each first `click` within an `input` element all of the field contents will be selected. Any subsequent `click` will clear the selection and position the caret at the actual mouse click coordinates. Whenever the `input` element will loose the focus this logic will be re-initialized.

The `html` and `code` are written for `angular 2+` but it's quite simple to adapt it to any other coding framework.

Answer (score -2):

Its not briliant buy may help you

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PC6VY/)

Basic : Overwrite what is already there...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t1').focus();
    $('#t1').val($('#t1').val());                      
}); ​
```